# For loop is being skipped and I don't know why

Tags: c#

So I am doing task from one site and my for loop decides to not cooperate with me and is skipping itself without a reason or at least for me.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    NbYear(1500, 5, 100, 5000);
    NbYear(1500000, 2.5, 10000, 2000000);
    NbYear(1500000, 0.25, 1000, 2000000);
}

public static int NbYear(int p0, double percent, int aug, int p)
{
    int a = 0;
    double result = 0;
    for (; result >= p; a++)
    {
        result = p0 * percent + aug;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(a);
    return a;
}
```

The outcome is 0,0,0 when it should be 15,10 and 94

Comment: What does the debugger say about the loop's condition, `result >= p`? Did you step through it?

Comment: `0 >= 5000` seems false to me.

Comment: idk what od u mean by that @madreflection

Comment: **[Using the free, built-in Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)** to debug your code is easier than you think.  It will also help you learn how code executes which will help you write better code.

Comment: I think you want to change your condition from `>=` to `<=`, because I think your intent is to continue to accumulate until you reach some threshold. That being said, every single execution of your for loop will be the same (the only variable changing is `a`, which isn't used), so if you do solve your problem and it does execute your for loop, it'll execute it forever.

Comment: In other words, you probably don't want to *assign* to result in your loop, but add something to a variable each time through, so result, or one of the other variables involved in the calculation, change in such a way that the loop termination condition happens properly.

Comment: ye @Steve you right i did it yesterday and it worked thanks you all for your time you spend to provide me with answers

Answer (score 4):

Result is initialized as 0, and 0 is not greater than any of provided p values.